# How to set wordpress thumbnail to stretch image to fill set width?

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem is seen here:
http://aivarasdaukantas.lt/demo/#tf-naujienos
(the second post)

Thumbnail size is set:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(250, 165, array('top','left'));
```

Comment: Do you have  `width: 100%;`  for that particular class?

Comment: it helps but is streches picture unproportionally

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems (from the name of your pictures) that you're using the thumbnail version in your template, but the full version instead - they're just stretched with the use of the `height` and `width` arguments.

I suggest to use  [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) in your template to get the thumb version of your image:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: nah mate, is use it too:

`code`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 service" >
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 post thumb">
    <h4><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong></h4>
    
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
     <p><em><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></em></p>
   </div>
   </div>

   <hr>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <p><?php _e('Sorry, there are no posts.'); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>`code`

Comment: Well then it doesn't feels like your thumbnail are generated. I suggest to give a go to Nefro answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need regenerate thumbnail ?

Try this plugin "https://lt.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/"